# Dataplotly with a temporal integration (QGIS)?

Tags: qgis, spatio-temporal-data, temporal-controller, plotly, dataplotly

I want to perform statistics on a dataset in time frames or specific dates.

I've been trying to figure out how to make the DataPlotly plots time dependent (using the QGIS Temporal controller). I tried doing this also on the Layout, giving temporal range -doing an atlas controlled attribute, but i couldn't make it.

I'm working on spatio-temporal correlations and i have a 3D (x,y,z) data set with a bunch of features in each point. There is no raster, or shapefile layer. Only PointZ layers.

Any ideas on how to develop this on QGIS?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a simple task. We have at least 2 sets of API (QGIS and Plotly) and integrating them together, also in the print layout with atlas is challenging. We have already a feature request in the repository: https://github.com/ghtmtt/DataPlotly/issues/33